# Riddle of the Black Knights

Tags: riddle

> As per their long-time ritual
>   The Black Knights sat in a circle.
>   The captain sat at the head,
>   and to his right the colonel.
>   A runt sat left of the captain,
>   half the size of the colonel.
>   A bold accuser stood in the center,
>   and quietly his votes were cast.
>   When the captain was accused, not once, but twice,
>   the silence did not last.

What is happening here?

Comment: I haven't been paying that close attention, so could it possibly be rot13(gur Gehzc vzcrnpuzrag gevny)?

Comment: @Avi, Lol, good guess, but this isn't it.  No specific knowledge required for this riddle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the answer is

> It's 12 o'clock!

Explanation:
As per their long-time ritual

> Clocks are very related to time!

The Black Knights sat in a circle.

> The Black Knights are the numerals around the face of the clock.

The captain sat at the head,
and to his right the colonel.
A runt sat left of the captain,
half the size of the colonel.

> The captain is '12', the colonel is '11', and the runt is '1' (which is half of '11' by physical size).
>  The left and right might seem backwards, but it must be from the point of view of the captain.

A bold accuser stood in the center,
and quietly his votes were cast.

> The accuser is the hands of the clock pointing at the Knights.

When the captain was accused, not once, but twice,
the silence did not last.

> When both hands of the clock point towards the captain, the clock rings the chime.

Comment: Almost certainly right, but a quibble - the silence would be broken any time the captain was accused, no?

Comment: Well done :) And @Rubio, yes you are correct, although this particular event is more notable. (It's been a while since I've visited these types of knights).

Comment: Thank you! A wonderful riddle. @Rubio This is true, although I never said otherwise!

Comment: You’re both [technically correct](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/909/991/48c.jpg). :)

Comment: As for the "point of view", that's even explicit in the text, since it does use the word "his".